# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Custom object returning null when POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a list of objects in my view, but in the post method, the parameter coming in is null.  The create page loads fine with all the information I want, but when I click "Create" I get the error listed in my title. What can I be doing wrong?

> Employees have an availability linked to them for each day. That's what i am trying to achieve

**Model**

```
public class Availability
{

    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Weekday")]
    public string weekday { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)] 
    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee employee { get; set; }

}
}
```

**Custom Class**

```
public class SetAvailability
{
    public long EmpID { get; set; }
    public String firstName {get; set;}
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    public Availability availability {get; set;}


}
```

**Controller methods**

```
// GET: /Availability/Create

    public ActionResult  Create(long id)
    {
        string[] weekdays ={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
        //find the employee
        Employee emp = db.Employees.Find(id);

        //create a list of setAvailability objects for each day 
        List<SetAvailability> editor = new List<SetAvailability>();


        //instantiate each SetAvailability object and populate accordingly for 7 days
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            //create a blank SetAvilability
            var _editor = new SetAvailability();

            //create a blank availability
            _editor.availability = new Availability();

            //set the weekday 
            _editor.availability.weekday = weekdays[i].ToString();

            //set the employee id, first name and last name
            _editor.EmpID = emp.Id;
            _editor.firstName = emp.FirstName;
            _editor.lastName = emp.LastName;
            //add the _editor to the editorlist
            editor.Add(_editor);
        }

        return View(editor);


    }

    //
    // POST: /Availability/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(List<SetAvailability> dto)
    {
        //dto object is coming in null! (checked by debugging) 
        List<SetAvailability> temp = new List<SetAvailability>();
        temp = dto;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // set the values for each availability object 
            //    breaks here!
            foreach (var item in dto)
            {                    
                // get the employee
                item.availability.employee = db.Employees.Find(item.EmpID);

                // weekday should already be set
                // start and end times should come in from the create view

                db.Availability.Add(item.availability);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","employee");
        }

        return View(temp);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model List<VolumeV2.Models.DTOs.SetAvailability>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";

}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Availability</legend>

    <table>
        <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)                
            {               
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.EmpID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.firstName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.lastName)
            <td>
               @Html.LabelFor(model => item.availability.weekday)
            </td>                
            <td>
               @Html.LabelFor(model => item.availability.StartTime)                
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.LabelFor(model => item.availability.EndTime)                
            </td>                
            break;
        }
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model){
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.EmpID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.firstName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.lastName)
            <tr>
                <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => item.availability.weekday)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelitem => item.availability.weekday)
                </td>

                <td>                           
                @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => item.availability.StartTime)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelitem => item.availability.StartTime)
                </td>

                <td>                          
                @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => item.availability.EndTime)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelitem => item.availability.EndTime)
                </td>
           </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try Editor Templates.

Comment: would you happen to know of a good basic MVC4 tutorial for them? I've had trouble finding a good source

Answer (score 0):

Try this

To get the collection of object at **POST** methods it need to modified Html.BeginForm,
add following Helper class in your application which will return you List of objects.
(e.g location of Helper class DemoApplication/Models/)

```
public static class HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions
    {
        private const string idsToReuseKey = "__htmlPrefixScopeExtensions_IdsToReuse_";

        public static IDisposable BeginCollectionItem(this HtmlHelper html, string collectionName)
        {
            var idsToReuse = GetIdsToReuse(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, collectionName);
            string itemIndex = idsToReuse.Count > 0 ? idsToReuse.Dequeue() : Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            // autocomplete="off" is needed to work around a very annoying Chrome behaviour whereby it reuses old values after the user clicks "Back", which causes the xyz.index and xyz[...] values to get out of sync.
            html.ViewContext.Writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"{0}.index\" autocomplete=\"off\" value=\"{1}\" />", collectionName, html.Encode(itemIndex)));

            return BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(html, string.Format("{0}[{1}]", collectionName, itemIndex));
        }

        public static IDisposable BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldPrefix)
        {
            return new HtmlFieldPrefixScope(html.ViewData.TemplateInfo, htmlFieldPrefix);
        }

        private static Queue<string> GetIdsToReuse(HttpContextBase httpContext, string collectionName)
        {
            // We need to use the same sequence of IDs following a server-side validation failure,  
            // otherwise the framework won't render the validation error messages next to each item.
            string key = idsToReuseKey + collectionName;
            var queue = (Queue<string>)httpContext.Items[key];
            if (queue == null) {
                httpContext.Items[key] = queue = new Queue<string>();
                var previouslyUsedIds = httpContext.Request[collectionName + ".index"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previouslyUsedIds))
                    foreach (string previouslyUsedId in previouslyUsedIds.Split(','))
                        queue.Enqueue(previouslyUsedId);
            }
            return queue;
        }

        private class HtmlFieldPrefixScope : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly TemplateInfo templateInfo;
            private readonly string previousHtmlFieldPrefix;

            public HtmlFieldPrefixScope(TemplateInfo templateInfo, string htmlFieldPrefix)
            {
                this.templateInfo = templateInfo;

                previousHtmlFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
                templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = htmlFieldPrefix;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = previousHtmlFieldPrefix;
            }
        }
    }
```

after that modified you view

```
    @model List<VolumeV2.Models.DTOs.SetAvailability>



    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";

    }

    <h2>Create</h2>


@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Availability</legend>

            <table>

                @foreach (var item in Model)                
                    {    

                    @Html.Partial("_partialView",item)
                }


            </table>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
      }

        <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>

        @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        }
```

create a partial view 
_partailView.cshtml

```
 @model VolumeV2.Models.DTOs.SetAvailability
     @using DemoApplication.Models  // Added Helper class reference
    <tr>
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("dto")) {

                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmpID)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.firstName)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.lastName)
                        <td>
                           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.availability.weekday)
                        </td>                
                        <td>
                           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.availability.StartTime)                
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.availability.EndTime)                
                        </td>                
                        break;

                      }
          </tr>
```

NOTE: you must keep same name of  Html.BeginCollectionItem("dto") and Parameter name in POST method otherwise you will not get value in POST method and also add **Helper class reference** in your view.

Comment: I've added in the html helper class to my project and included it in the view, as well as changed the beginCollectionItem ad now my create button wont do anything

Answer (score 0):

To fix this up quickly, you may use the indexing on the list items using a "for" loop since that will render the name of the controls to suite the naming convention for MVC model binding. For e.g, [0].availability.weekday, [1].availability.weekday etc., that represent an array of items with corresponding index to be able to construct a list of items while Model Binding.

```
@model List<MvcApplication5.Models.SetAvailability>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Employee")) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Availability</legend>

    <table>
        <tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].EmpID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].firstName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].lastName)
            <td>
               @Html.LabelFor(model => Model[i].availability.weekday)
            </td>                
            <td>
               @Html.LabelFor(model => Model[i].availability.StartTime)                
            </td>
            <td>
               @Html.LabelFor(model => Model[i].availability.EndTime)                
            </td>                
            break;
        }
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
           @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].EmpID)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].firstName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model[i].lastName)
            <tr>
                <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => Model[i].availability.weekday)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelitem => Model[i].availability.weekday)
                </td>

                <td>                           
                @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => Model[i].availability.StartTime)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelitem => Model[i].availability.StartTime)
                </td>

                <td>                          
                @Html.EditorFor(modelitem => Model[i].availability.EndTime)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelitem => Model[i].availability.EndTime)
                </td>
           </tr>  
        }
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

And now, you should see seven items in the list after the POST. Hope this help you.